# Stochastic processes and independence

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I have a question about stochastic processes in general. This question is out of pure curiosity. I am self-teaching myself this stuff as a hobby so this question is not related to any particular problem.

Let's say that there is some Gaussian wide seance stationary process $X(t)$. Are realizations at different times independent? In other words, is $X(2)$ ***necessarily*** independent of $X(1)$? Is $X$ independent identically distributed at various times?

I appreciate any guidance. The book I have (Essentials of Stochastic Processes) is not clear on this point and I am unable to find much info on various internet searches.

Comment: "The book I have" : which book? If someone else has read it, had the same question and found the answer, they will be of help.

Comment: Good point. I have updated the original post to include the book title.